# Regex pattern to allow all ASCII characters values with some exception

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write regex expression which will allow all ASCII characters, with the exception of following ASCII characters which will be restricted

> : ~*\^_`?<>

How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the character set `[\u0000-\u007f]` to match all ASCII characters, and combine it with negative lookahead for the characters you want to exclude in another character set preceeding it:

```
^(?:(?![: ~*\\^_`?<>)])[\u0000-\u007f])*$
```

It would be possible to combine these into a single positive character set, but it'd be much more difficult to understand.

Comment: Hello thank you for your quick response, however, in the input field, I even want to allow spaces. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Spaces are contained in the "with the exception of following ASCII characters which will be restricted" set in your question. Did you not mean to put them there? If you want spaces, remove the space from the negative character set in the pattern.

Comment: Ok got it, Thank you so much for your help!